# Computer keeps restarting when trying to open py2app application

Tags: python, tkinter, py2app

I've made a really simple desktop app using Tkinter. When I set up everything in py2app the program looks like its generated fine, but when I click on it to open my computer restarts everytime. The code will run fine when I run it out of the Python IDE, but my screen goes black and restarts and brings me back to the MacOS login page when I try to run it by clicking on the icon or running the py2app version from the terminal. Has anyone run into this issue?

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter

# importing everyting from tkinter
# expression to access among all the functions
expression = ""
# functions
def input_number(number, equation):
   # accessing the global expression variable
   global expression
   # concatenation of string
   expression = expression + str(number)
   equation.set(expression)
def clear_input_field(equation):
   global expression
   expression = ""
   # setting empty string in the input field
   equation.set("Enter the expression")
def evaluate(equation):
    global expression
    # trying to evaluate the expression
    try:
        result = str(eval(expression))
        # showing the result in the input field
        equation.set(result)
        # setting expression to empty string
        expression = ""
    except:
    # some error occured
    # showing it to the user equation.set("Enter a valid expression")
        expression = ""

def new_calc():
   new_window = Tk()
   new_window.title("A whole new window")
   # set the configuration of GUI window
   new_window.geometry("450x220")
   print('This is a new window!')

    
# creating the GUI
def main():
   # main window
   window = Tk()
   # setting the title of GUI window
   window.title("Calculator")
   # set the configuration of GUI window
   window.geometry("450x220")
   # varible class instantiation
   equation = StringVar()
   # input field for the expression
   input_field = Entry(window, textvariable=equation)
   input_field.place(height=100)
   # we are using grid position
   # for the arrangement of the widgets
   input_field.grid(columnspan=4, ipadx=100, ipady=5)
   # settin the placeholder message for users
   equation.set("Enter the expression")
   # creating buttons and placing them at respective positions
   _1 = Button(window, text='1', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(1, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _1.grid(row=2, column=0)
   _2 = Button(window, text='2', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(2, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _2.grid(row=2, column=1)
   _3 = Button(window, text='3', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(3, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _3.grid(row=2, column=2)
   _4 = Button(window, text='4', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(4, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _4.grid(row=3, column=0)
   _5 = Button(window, text='5', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(5, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _5.grid(row=3, column=1)
   _6 = Button(window, text='6', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(6, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _6.grid(row=3, column=2)
   _7 = Button(window, text='7', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(7, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _7.grid(row=4, column=0)
   _8 = Button(window, text='8', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(8, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _8.grid(row=4, column=1)
   _9 = Button(window, text='9', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(9, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _9.grid(row=4, column=2)
   _0 = Button(window, text='0', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number(0, equation), height=2, width=7)
   _0.grid(row=5, column=0)
   plus = Button(window, text='+', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number('+', equation), height=2, width=7)
   plus.grid(row=2, column=3)
   minus = Button(window, text='-',bd=0, command=lambda: input_number('-', equation), height=2, width=7)
   minus.grid(row=3, column=3)
   multiply = Button(window, text='*', bd=0, command=lambda:  input_number('*', equation), height=2, width=7)
   multiply.grid(row=4, column=3)
   divide = Button(window, text='/', bd=0, command=lambda: input_number('/', equation), height=2, width=7)
   divide.grid(row=5, column=3)
   equal = Button(window, text='=', bd=0, command=lambda: evaluate(equation), height=2, width=7)
   equal.grid(row=5, column=2)
   clear = Button(window, text='Clear', bd=0, command=lambda: clear_input_field(equation), height=2, width=7)
   clear.grid(row=5, column=1)
   # showing the GUI
   window.mainloop()
# start of the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Here is the setup file:

```
from setuptools import Extension, setup

APP = ['CalcApp.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
 'iconfile':'Calculator.icns',
 'argv_emulation': True,
 'packages': ['certifi'],
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: Can you share a [mre]? Does your application run any subprocess or batch/bash commands?

Comment: Yes I just added it to the post.

Comment: code is too long - you don't need all these buttons to test code - reduce it to minimal code which still makes problem. Maybe when you will remove some elements from code then you find element which makes problem. And after creating code with py2app first run code manually in console/terminal instead of clicking on it - maybe it will display some error message in console before reset.

Comment: BTW: `tkinter` is only wrapper on script language `tcl` and its module `tk` - you may have to maunally add these elements (C/C++ libraries) to your project to create correct program. If you will use PyInstaller to create program then in its documentation you should find some information how to manually add other module and libraries.